# Can we convert a string to JSON Array using the json-simple-1.1.1.jar library?

Tags: java, json

I want to convert a string into a JSON Array using the `json-simple-1.1.1.jar` library and came up with the following code,

```
import org.json.simple.*;


public class RESTclient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String output = "[{\"Symbol\":\"AMZN\",\"Name\":\"Amazon.com Inc\",\"Exchange\":\"NASDAQ\"},{\"Symbol\":\"VXAZN\",\"Name\":\"CBOE Amazon VIX Index\",\"Exchange\":\"Market Data Express\"}]";

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(output);

        String[] names = JSONObject.getNames(jsonObject);

        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.toJSONArray(new JSONArray(names));

        System.out.println(jsonArray);
    }

}
```

I want the output to be a JSON Array. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *What am I doing wrong here?*

You're trying to convert a `String` that contains a JSON array into a `JSONObject`

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(output);
```

Your content represents a JSON array so parse it as such

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) parser.parse(output);
```

---

Note that other libraries, like Gson and Jackson, have much better abstractions for JSON arrays and objects (`JsonArray`, `ArrayNode`). Consider using those instead.