# JAVA - read Json elements

Tags: java, json

I have a snippet that returns me a string like that:

```
String str = "[{"id":"1", "name":"diego"},{"id":"2", "name":"john"}]";
```

I don't know, if this is exactly a JSON object, but I need to read the fields (and put them in a structure). I tried without success.

I am using Json-simple-1.1.1.jar

Anyone can help me? Thankyou in advance!

Solved:

```
String sss = "[{\"id\":\"1\", \"name\":\"diego\"},{\"id\":\"2\", \"name\":\"john\"}]";

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONArray jsonarray = (JSONArray) parser.parse(sss);

    JSONObject obj1 = (JSONObject) jsonarray.get(1);    
    System.out.println(obj1.get("id"));
```

Comment: Please show the code you have written.  We are not a code writing service.  If you don't make any effort it's unlikely anyone will help you.

Comment: Please do not use the question area for answers/solutions. This is really confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can find the solution from this question:

[Can we convert a string to JSON Array using the json-simple-1.1.1.jar library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36805754/can-we-convert-a-string-to-json-array-using-the-json-simple-1-1-1-jar-library)

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) parser.parse(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String sss = "[{\"id\":\"1\", \"name\":\"diego\"},{\"id\":\"2\", \"name\":\"john\"}]";

JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) parser.parse(sss);

System.out.println(jsonArray);
```

the output is `[{"name":"diego","id":"1"},{"name":"john","id":"2"}]` but i still don't know how to get the elements inside