# How to parse a single array, without a name associated with it?

Tags: java, json

I have the following JSON:

```
[{
    "aaa": "blah",
    "ddd": 2
}]
```

Note that the map is inside an array. How to get the map and then the value of "aaa".

Using Json Simple.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse JSON objects from a JSONArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47436239/how-do-i-parse-json-objects-from-a-jsonarray)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36805754/can-we-convert-a-string-to-json-array-using-the-json-simple-1-1-1-jar-library

Answer (score -1):

The following code should work. Let me know if it doesn't!

```
Object obj = JSONValue.parse(jsonString);
JSONArray array = (JSONArray)obj;
JSONObject obj2 = (JSONObject)array.get(0);
String result = obj2.get("aaa")
```